# Hibernate 5 get certain columns from table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate. I want to first get from a specific row only certain columns, that's what I did:

```
User user = (User) session
            .createQuery("select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email from User u where id=:id")
            .setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
```

and I get this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to org.seklyza.recipy.entities.User`

What's wrong here?

Another thing that I don't know how to also select certain columns when I'm trying to get all rows. This is how I get all columns, but I want to get only firstName, lastName and email.

```
for (Object o : session.createQuery("FROM User").getResultList()) {
        users.add((User) o);
}
```

thanks!

(I know it's recipe and not recipy)

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflict in your `imports`, so to solve your problem you should to :

1. Change the **User** to the real Entity `package.of.my.entity.User`, or something like this: `com.entities.User` like :

```
package.to.my.entity.User user = (package.to.my.entity.User) session.createQuery("select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email from User u where id=:id").setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
```

2. make sure that you delete the `org.seklyza.recipy.entities.User` from your **imports**

**EDIT**

alwayse getSingleResult make problems, change it to :

```
List<User> user = session.createQuery("select u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email from User u where id=:id").setParameter("id", id).getResultList();

if(user!=null){
   return user.get(0);
}else{
   //there are no results
   return null
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: org.seklyza.recipy.entities.User is the entity class

Comment: are you sure this is the problem, maybe you call another method can you comment it and try to work or not @shabenda

Comment: mmm, now i understand

Comment: @shabenda i'm sorry now i'm soo tired maybe tomorrow i will

Comment: It's OK. Good night, don't worry.